# unable to select an element using xpath using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, automation

I'm trying to automate a process using selenium and have been able to open a webpage and click on links, however I stumbled upon a table in which a link needs to be clicked but I'm unable to select that link and getting an error. need help to select that particular element

right now this is what I've done

```
elem2=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[3]/a::text')
elem2.click()
```

you can see in the picture that I'm trying to access the findhtml.org link.

the error that I get is

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression /html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[3]/a::text because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[3]/a::text' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.113)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the specific link try below code.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `presence_of_element_located`() and following xpath.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://publicrecords.netronline.com/state/IL/county/dupage")
element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@href='http://www.dupageco.org/PropertyInfo/PropertyLookUp.aspx' and contains(.,'Go to Data')]")))
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
element.click()
```

Please note the element is **not** inside any `iframe`

Comment: but can you explain to me what did these new imports did and how they helped to click on the link?

Comment: @reduxHelpPlz : its wait for the element to be available on the page and click.It get rid of synchronization issue which sometime cause error to find element.

Comment: okay. so before I was using `find_element_by_link_text` and then adding click() on that element which would sometimes shows interrupt or other error. so this method is more efficient and I should replace the earlier clicking event with this new clicking code?

Comment: Two things my code will do.1) This will solve the synchronization issue. 2) since item you are searching it bottom of the table so you need to scroll into element  `element.location_once_scrolled_into_view` and then click. Hope you understood the entire code now.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to switch to the `iframe`

Example:

```
frame = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@src, \'hbx.media.net\')]')
browser.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

Now you can click

```
link = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, \'http://www.findhtml.org\')]')
link.click()
```

Comment: getting an error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` under the 'x' of hbx.net

Comment: escape the url with \ or add double quotes "

Comment: now a new error `NameError: name 'driver' is not defined`

Comment: should it be browser instead of driver for me

Comment: I tried doing browser too instead of driver and getting this error `InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid 'id'`

Comment: I have corrected the example to use 'browser' but there is no id in the example i provided so you have an problem somewhere in your code...

Answer (score 1):

```
browser.get('https://publicrecords.netronline.com/state/IL/county/dupage')

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(text(),'DuPage Supervisor of Assessments')]//following-sibling::td[2]//a"))).click()
```

output:

[image]

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: getting error as `NameError: name 'driver' is not defined`

Comment: check updated solution , use browser instead of driver

Comment: `TimeoutException: Message: ` this is the new error.. i waited for 1 minute, didn't click anywhere and got the timeout error

Comment: can you share your url ? Also where you got this error while switching or while clicking on your td element

Comment: got the error in this line `EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, '_mN_cksync_0')))`

Comment: @DipakBachhav : There is no iframe to switch.why are you providing wrong info?